# Show a message when there are chat messages from ignored users over certain time period

Tags: feature-request, chat, ignored-users

I just noticed this weird behavior in chat:

[image: chat with blank space between time periods]

Before submitting a bug report about it, I checked the transcript and turns out there was a message from an ignored user in that gap, so this isn't really a bug.

However, on the sites, we get such a banner:

> Hiding questions because of your Ignored Tags preferences for tags:

Can this be applied to chat as well?

Rough mockup:

[image: mockup of the proposed change in chat]

Comment: I really like how discord is handling this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUfPa.png

Comment: @sam huh, I don't like Discord but this is indeed pretty neat.

Comment: (as bonus discord also hides the replies of others to the two users I blocked - great interface!)

Comment: This can also be confusing when there are two messages from the same person right after each other (so chat would normally collapse them into one speech bubble), but since an ignored message was right in between, the message bubbles separate for no obvious reason.

Comment: @bobble don't remember seeing such thing, but yeah sounds confusing as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I've seen it quite a bit, especially after ignoring a user who kept trying to insert themselves into conversations I was having. They kept at it, so I would still know exactly when they were attempting to communicate due to odd message break-ups.